# Hacer post con una api y GuzzleHttp

Tags: php

Buenas noches es la primera vez que utilizo GuzzleHttp. Bien estoy utilizando ActiveCampaing que es para gestionar newsletters.

Bien lo primero que hice fue consultar la documentación, donde pone lo siguiente:

```
curl -H "Api-Token: YOUR_TOKEN" https://account.api-us1.com/api/3/
```

Y luego para hacer un post hacer lo siguiente:

```
https://youraccountname.api-us1.com/api/3/contacts
```

Bien, pues lo segundo que hice, me fui a postman para probar si funciona.

Entonces le di a `inport` para meterle la dirección del curl.
Lo puse en formato RAW y JSON dentro del body.
Y por último le hice un post en JSON tal y como pide la documentación.

```
{
    "contact": {
        "email": "email@example.com"
    }
}
```

Y el resultado es 201 Created y entrando en la aplicación de ActiveCampaign el cliente a sido añadido.
Bien el problema es a la hora de hacer una prueba en mi aplicación de Laravel.

Instale GuzzleHttp
Y estoy haciendo lo siguiente:

```
 $headers = [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Api-Token' => 'mi token API que me da ActiveCampaign',
            "Cache-Control" => "no-cache",
        ];

        $client = new Client();
       

        $response = $client->request('POST', 'https://usuario.api-us1.com/api/3/contacts', [
            'form_params' => [
                'email' => 'hola@correo.es'
            ],
            $headers,
        ]);

dd($response);
```

Pero me devuelve este error:

> Client error: `POST https://usuario.api-us1.com/api/3/contacts/`
> resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response

Parece que no tengo autorización, ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal??

Gracias

Comment: ¿Seguro que el TOKEN que le estás pasando es válido? ¿Verificaste si tienes permisos para acceder al recurso `contacts`?

Comment: Si, si que es el correcto. Encontre como solucionarlo ahora lo publico